# one-to-many IPC

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, one-to-many, shared-memory

I'm looking for an ipc mechanism which would allow high throughput of data updates from one process to many (thousands).

The 'server' process would be responsible for updating a data structure at a high frequency.  Upon update, I'd like to notify the 'client' processes of the update, and allow those processes to read the new data.

Under a Linux or FreeBSD environment, what would be a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). It's a fast, lightweight, cross-platform, cross-language messaging system that already does all you're asking for. It's easy to use, and very robust. It can operate in many, many modes, one of which is one to many messaging (this is called broadcast in CS-speak).

Answer (score 2):

While not clear on your setup limitations or requirements (all processes in the same machine?), it looks that the most versatile solution would be to use [MPI](http://mpi-forum.org/) which is platform-independent and distributed.  In particular, it provides [broadcasting functionality](http://www.mpitutorial.com/mpi-broadcast-and-collective-communication).

The downside is that you would have to model your design a bit after the MPI API.