# native bus based event notify mechanism in unix/linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc

Suppose an embedded system which is running different set of softwares which should be communicated together asynchronously, i implemented the data communication mechanism using shared memory ( its fast and simple to use ).
In case of IPC in multiple softwares with different technologies, i was getting into the problem how to notify softwares like a bus mechanism. while there are good IPC/notify mechanism such as unix signal/eventfd/shared semaphores/unix sockets and ..., as i know all of them can be used as point-to-point notification system and i can't find any native solution for bus like notification system.
In BUS notification system, one can notify multiple slaves in single bus notification, rather than creating multiple notification objects for each slave and call notify for all of them.

I know there are already working systems such as D-BUS, but D-BUS is considered too complex for small embedded system and i am looking for native solutions.
Is there any simple, lightweight and native event notification system like D-BUS in linux/unix ?

I found that inotify could be used in such case, but i think is there any 
other method exists which was designed for notification propose only?

EDIT:
I think multicast IPC (which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776694/multicast-ipc-options-in-unix) is sightly different from publish/subscribe or BUS.

To be clear, i found that inotify could be used in this situation, suppose on file and multiple file watchers which resembles publish/subscribe IPC pattern, i want to know is there any other solution to this problem?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multicast IPC options in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776694/multicast-ipc-options-in-unix)

Comment: @bobah i saw that question before, the question asks about multicast which is sightly different from bus

Comment: Please take some time to review ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The answer to the linked question also suggests there is nothing yet which is directly usable as a bus. If you are up to using middleware than the variety of choice exists, starting from things like zeromq.

Comment: @bobah disagree, inotify could be used exactly for this situation, suppose there is one file and multiple softwares looking for file changes. but i am concerned about using inotify in this case, idon't know is it correct solution or not